# Get multi level relationship in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, tree, cypher

Here SuperUser created Sunil. Sunil created ravi ... Divya created Ramya.

[image: My DB values]

When I query like this

```
match (a:Login{Type:"SuperUser"})<-[:createdBy*0..5]-(m) return *
```

I am getting the same response as in the picture. But from the JSON I cant able to figure out who is created by whom. I need the response something like

```
{"n":{"id":"SuperUser","created":[{"id":"sunil","created":[{"id":"ravi","created":[{"id":"Prem"},{"id":"Divya","created":[{"id":"Ramya"}]}]}]}]}}
```

So that I can know who is created by whom. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that information explicitly in your return clause. Use this query.

```
MATCH (a:Login{Type:"SuperUser"})<-[:createdBy*0..5]-(m)
WITH collect(m) as source
WITH source, range(0, size(source)) AS index
UNWIND index as i
WITH source[i] as m
MATCH (m:Login)-[:createdBy]->(n:Login) RETURN m.Name as user, n.Name as CreatedBy
```

You can use *ORDER BY* clause to group the data as well.

Comment: Thanks its worked. But the JSON is not similar as I metioned in the post. Can we do anything more to get the exact output as I mentioned in the question??? Thanks a lot

Comment: This query will get you the relationship for user->creater. You can write a simple python script to create your required JSON format.

Comment: Ya I already did that. That the reason to accept the answer. But I want to know it is possible through query or not

Comment: To be honest, i am not sure. I will try when i get a chance and will update here if possible. Meanwhile you are good to go as you have already written the code :)

Comment: @RaviShankerReddy You may want to take a look at the [JSON conversion procedures and functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_from_tojson) in APOC Procedures.